# How do i fix my duplicating QuickSort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Im having some problems with figuring out what is wrong with the following quicksort. The problem exists it doesnt sort everything correctely and even looks like it duplicates numbers

```
public static List<Archer> quickSort(List<Archer> archers, Comparator<Archer> scoringScheme) {
        var sortedArray = archers.toArray(new Archer[archers.size()]);
        quickSort(sortedArray, 0, archers.size(), scoringScheme);
        return Arrays.asList(sortedArray);


    }
```

```
 private static void quickSort(Archer[] array, int min, int max, Comparator<Archer> scoringScheme) {
        if (min >= max - 1) {
            return;
        }
        int pivot = (min + max) / 2;
        var pivotItem = array[pivot];
        var lowerIndex = min;
        var higherIndex = max - 1;
        while (lowerIndex <= higherIndex) {
            while (lowerIndex <= higherIndex && scoringScheme.compare(array[lowerIndex], pivotItem) <= 0) {
                lowerIndex++;
            }
            while (higherIndex >= lowerIndex && scoringScheme.compare(array[higherIndex], pivotItem) >= 0) {
                higherIndex--;
            }
            if (lowerIndex < higherIndex) {
                var temp = array[lowerIndex];
                array[lowerIndex] = array[higherIndex];
                array[higherIndex] = temp;
                lowerIndex++;
                higherIndex--;
            }
        }
        if (lowerIndex > pivot) {
            lowerIndex--;
            array[pivot] = array[lowerIndex];
            array[lowerIndex] = pivotItem;
        } else {
            higherIndex++;
            array[pivot] = array[higherIndex];
            array[higherIndex] = pivotItem;
        }
        quickSort(array, min, lowerIndex , scoringScheme);
        quickSort(array, higherIndex +1, max, scoringScheme);

    }
```

the result is following:

```
Expected [135810 ( 187 / 217), 135810 ( 184 / 214), 135810 ( 183 / 213), 135810 ( 179 / 209), 135810 ( 177 / 207), 135810 ( 176 / 206), 135810 ( 170 / 200), 135810 ( 167 / 197), 135810 ( 167 / 197), 135810 ( 165 / 195), 135810 ( 162 / 192), 135810 ( 161 / 191), 135810 ( 161 / 191), 135810 ( 158 / 188), 135810 ( 158 / 188), 135810 ( 151 / 181), 135810 ( 151 / 181), 135810 ( 150 / 180), 135810 ( 147 / 177), 135810 ( 147 / 177), 135810 ( 146 / 176), 135810 ( 140 / 170), 135810 ( 138 / 168)]
Actual [135810 ( 187 / 217), 135810 ( 187 / 217), 135810 ( 184 / 214), 135810 ( 179 / 209), 135810 ( 177 / 207), 135810 ( 176 / 206), 135810 ( 176 / 206), 135810 ( 167 / 197), 135810 ( 167 / 197), 135810 ( 165 / 195), 135810 ( 165 / 195), 135810 ( 162 / 192), 135810 ( 162 / 192), 135810 ( 158 / 188), 135810 ( 158 / 188), 135810 ( 158 / 188), 135810 ( 158 / 188), 135810 ( 151 / 181), 135810 ( 151 / 181), 135810 ( 150 / 180), 135810 ( 150 / 180), 135810 ( 147 / 177), 135810 ( 147 / 177)]
```

Comment: Your algorithm seems to compare not only the elements themselves, but also their indexes. I don't think the latter is right, you can't make assumptions about array indexes like that.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: The index comparison is there to skip elements that are already in the correct partition. The comparison proper isn't shown here.

Comment: It's just that when I look up the canonical implementation, there's a lot less of this swapping going on in there. Namely, everything that's right after the `while` loop and before recursion in your code isn't there in classical version, and in classical version they don't partition by `lo` and `hi`, they use `pivotIndex` for that.

Comment: I don't know what the "classical" version is, but you don't know what the final index of the pivot is beforehand. What I've seen often ist that the pivot is swapped to one end and then swapped back after partitioning.

Comment: @MOehm - this is a variation of Hoare partition scheme, where the pivot or elements equal to the pivot can end up anywhere after a partition step. After a step, all that is guaranteed is that the indexes point to the boundary between elements <= pivot and elements >= pivot. The code itself has issues though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the calling code, I'm not sure about the parameters. Suggested changes noted in comments. The code would be a bit simpler if the external call was

```
    quickSort(array, 0, length-1, compare);
```

this would eliminate the need for the max-1 in the code.

```
 private static void quickSort(Archer[] array, int min, int max, Comparator<Archer> scoringScheme) {
        if (min >= max - 1) {
            return;
        }
        int pivot = (min + max) / 2;        // may need to be (min+max-1)/2
        var pivotItem = array[pivot];
        var lowerIndex = min;
        var higherIndex = max - 1;
        while (lowerIndex <= higherIndex) {
            while (scoringScheme.compare(array[lowerIndex], pivotItem) < 0) {  // change
                lowerIndex++;
            }
            while (scoringScheme.compare(array[higherIndex], pivotItem) > 0) { // change
                higherIndex--;
            }
            if (lowerIndex <= higherIndex) {                // change (<=)
                var temp = array[lowerIndex];
                array[lowerIndex] = array[higherIndex];
                array[higherIndex] = temp;
                lowerIndex++;
                higherIndex--;
            }
        }
        // change ... deleted 9 lines
        quickSort(array, min, higherIndex+1 , scoringScheme);  // change
        quickSort(array, lowerIndex, max, scoringScheme);      // change

    }
```

Comment: I implemented it with a small change because of an indexOutOfbounds. I have the feelin it has to do with the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of quicksort implementation:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-quicksort

To avoid duplicated values, could you not use one of the implementations of the Set instead of List interface?If so, just implement **equals** and **hashcode** methods of you Archer object.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Include relevant parts of the code into your answer.

Comment: The linked to example is a variation of Lomuto scheme, while the code in the question is a variation of Hoare partition scheme.